# Replacing an escaped single quote with an escaped double quote in Python

Tags: python, regex, double-quotes, substitution

I'm trying to replace all single quotes with double quotes, but leave behind all escaped single quotes. Does anyone know a simple way to do this with python regexs?

```
Input:
"{ 'name': 'Skrillex', 'Genre':'Dubstep', 'Bass': 'Heavy', 'thoughts': 'this\'s ahmazing'}"

output:
"{ "name": "Skrillex", "Genre": "Dubstep", "Bass": "Heavy", "thoughts": "this\'s ahmazing"}"
```

Comment: Can't be done, since in the raw string they're all the same.

Comment: First question I have is why do you have to do this? Is this a JSON string? How did you get it?

Comment: yeah, look like he inserts special character into the database, and then, takes back the data to json format and send to the browser

Comment: Could your provide `repr(input_string)` to avoid ambiguity. For example, what is true: `input_string[0] == '"'` (that is you provided the input as you see it in a text file) or is it `input_string[0] == '{'` (that is you already provided `repr(input_string)`).

Comment: @pydsigner: [they are not](http://ideone.com/F9aRfA) if the input is interpreted so that first char is `'"'`.

Comment: Thanks for your input and questioning. I'm working with miss-properly formatted json(the creator used single quotes instead of double quotes). In order to load the json into python I needed to replace the single quotes. Since there were external links within the json(external links that used escaped  single quotes (\')) I needed to preserve those while replacing the double quotes. @DonkeyRocket's solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of...odd, but it may work. Remember to preface your string with `r` to denote a raw string so that we can remove the backslashes:

```
In [19]: s = r"{ 'name': 'Skrillex', 'Genre':'Dubstep', 'Bass': 'Heavy', 'thoughts': 'this\'s ahmazing'}"
In [20]: s.replace("\\'", 'REPLACEMEOHYEAH').replace("'", '"').replace('REPLACEMEOHYEAH', "\\'")
Out[20]: '{ "name": "Skrillex", "Genre":"Dubstep", "Bass": "Heavy", "thoughts": "this\'s ahmazing"}'
```

The `REPLACEMEOHYEAH` the token to replace, so it would need to be something that is not going to appear in your actual string. The response format looks like something that could be parsed in more natural way, but if that isn't an option this should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer. This is what I needed to complete this roundabout method. There's just one thing necessary to add to that trick and it'll be complete(I have added it by editing it directly.)

Comment: @LucianNovo Awesome, glad to hear it! I do not envy your task :)

Answer (score -1):

1. replace all the \' into a magic word
2. replace all the ' into "
3. replace all the magic words back to \'